# How can I match this pattern using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, string

I have strings coming into my application. Each incoming string is composed of substrings with no spaces between the substrings. For example, "ID1ID1ID1ID2ID2ID2", where "ID1" is a substring and "ID2" is a substring. I want a regular expression which can detect when there is a pattern where a substring surrounds a set of substrings that does not contain the first substring. So, for example "ID1ID2ID1", "ID1ID1ID3ID1", and "ID1ID2ID3ID2ID1" would all match. Along with the incoming string, I have the first substring in that string (i.e. ID1). So, using that first substring, I want to say "Match Any number of ID1s, then (any string that is not ID1), and then any number of ID1s".

As an example, what I have tried so far is:

```
.*ID1.*[^ID1]+ID1.*
```

I've just used regexpal to test this, and it seems to work ok. Is there a better way to do this though? I was looking into using lookarounds, but I couldn't see a way to use them since the lookaround doesn't consume any part of the string. Also, the fact that I am using the [^ID1] doesn't seem right since that just checks to see that the characters I, D, and 1 are not used. Thank you.

Comment: `[^ID1]` won't do the thing you want..

Comment: This all depends on the length of the substring. Is the substring always 3 characters?

Comment: No, it's not necessarily 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know its `ID1`, you can do this

```
 # (?:ID1)+(?:(?!ID1|[ ]).)+(?:ID1)+

 (?:                           # Cluster group, leading 'ID1' 
      ID1                           # An 'ID1'
 )+                            # End cluster, do 1 to many times

 (?:                           # Cluster group
      (?!                           # Lookahead NEGAGIVE assertion
           ID1                           # 'ID1'
        |  [ ]                           # or space
      )                             # End lookahead
      .                             # Assertion passed, grab any character
 )+                            # End cluster, do 1 to many times

 (?:                           # Cluster group, trailing 'ID1'
      ID1                           # An 'ID1'
 )+                            # End cluster, do 1 to many times
```

Comment: @Nick - Any regex syntax documentation. All `( .. )` are scoped  groups, in the sense of language scope. The specific constructs are determined by the characters immediately following the opening paren. `(..)` capture group. `(?: .. )` non-capture (ie. `cluster`) group, `(?=..)` `(?!=..)` `(?<=..)` `(?<!..)` lookaround assertions, etc...

Comment: Thank you. For any future reference, I also found information about this concept here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html.

Comment: @Nick - Ok, thanks. I use [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com) for practical creation/edit/testing of regular expressions. There comes a day when reading alone won't help.